# read the second row of a csv file into a dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

i have a csv file that looks something like this:

```
username,permission,type,avtar
user1,op,member,goldilock
user2,guest
user3,guest
```

The 'type' and 'avtar' data is only in the second row (user1), for user2 and user3 this will be empty.
What i am trying to achieve is get the type and avtar data from the second row and put that into a dict that would look like this:

```
{'type': 'member', 'avtar': 'goldilock'}
```

I tried to use the built-in csv.DictReader, i do not want to use panda for this. I can get all the contents of the csv file into a dict using the above module, but i do not knw how i can select a specific row and put them into a dict.

Following is the code that i have so far, is it possible to use DictReader module to achieve this at all? or there is another approach i should adopt?

```
import csv 
inputFile="test.csv"
with open(inputFile, "rb") as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print row['type']
```

Comment: By second row, you mean the first after the header?

Comment: yes thats right first row after header, when i meant the extra rows are empty i meant there will not be data. only the second row of those two columns holds data. (type and avtar)

Comment: DictReader does that, just iterate over it and select the row you want. For practice you can loop over the dictreader and print it

Comment: Actually what you want is the first row of _data_ in the file (the header doesn't count). This means you could simply do `row1 = next(csv.DictReader(data))`. The `DictReader` class in the `csv` module will take care of skipping the header—it uses it to determine the keys in the dictionary it returns after reading a row of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want one row, don't use a loop. Use the iterator

```
reader = csv.DictReader(data)
row2 = next(reader)
```